# frame of view collision method (push-back or force-back)

Tags: c++, view, collision, sfml, detection

trying to build-up an engine for a side-scroller.

My question is this, will tying character movement to simplistically hurt me in the long run. Should I be forcing character to remain in the frame-of-view as an absolute?

I'm at the point where I'm working out the methods for controlling the position of drawn objects relative to the player character and the frame-of-view. I have a working method;

```
//(pseudo-code):

level.limit.left = 0;              // level starts at x = 0
level.limit.right = 300;           // level ends at x = 300
view = viewsize(100, 100);         // window (frame-of-view) = 100 by 100
character.position.x = 200;        // current position of character sprite
view.position.x = 200;             // current center position of view
if (userInput.Left = true)         // catches isKeyPressed::left
{        
character.position.x +=1;          // move character left by 1
view.position.x += 1;              // move view left by 1 

//view collision detection
if (view.position.x > 250)
{   view.position.x -= 1;}        

if (view.position.x  < 50 )
{   view.position.x += 1; }

//character collision detection
if (character.position.x > 300)
{   character.position -= 1;  }

if (character.position.x < 0  ) 
{   character.position += 1;  }
```

This lets the character & view collide with the edge of level independently. However if character position changes by more than 1 character & view loss synch. I know collision detection will grow to encompass other sprites. Are there serious pitfalls to using this method that I'm not seeing??

Comment: Render position for character and its position in the game world may be different. Don't mix it up. Certainly do not tie the position of the character to the view on the screen directly. You may later make the view to follow the character, but that should happen at high level, not during the input handling, as in the code you showed us.

Comment: ? I didn't mention rendering or input handling. I'm trying to decide whether to bind the movements of "view" to "character". If they move as one there's no synch issues but there could be collision detection issues with the limits of the level if they don't move independently.